# navigationController crash

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, navigationcontroller

I have a question about iPhone develop

```
 CarDetailDetail *myview = [[[CarDetailDetail alloc] init] autorelease];

myview.detailMaintainID = self.detailMaintainID;
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:myview animated:YES];
```

this is work fine in iPhone 4 (iOS 4.3) and iPhone 3gs (iOS 5.X)

but iPod touch (iOS 4.2) will crash when I pop back one or two times, 
memory warning will appear and has bad access error

but when I not release *myview (remove autorelease keyword) , iPod works fine...

I don't know why , some one can help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with the YES/NO flag on the pop animation

If you find that you are getting no crash on your problem device with NO pop animation it probably indicates a timing issue of some sort.

In other words a block or web thread is trying to hit a view controller which has been deallocated already.

post your your console logs in the question too for more help.

Comment: I use yes or no , just only iPod touch crash , its os is 4.3.5 , is this os bug? I don't know... but thanks your answer

Answer (score 0):

try doing this

```
 CarDetailDetail *myview = [[CarDetailDetail alloc] initWithNibName:<name of view contrlle> bundle:nil];
 //Remove this bit of code myview.detailMaintainID = self.detailMaintainID;

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:myview animated:YES];
[myview release];
```